# How to add a row with a multi-word name to a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, row, typeerror

I have a dataframe in pandas (called `df`) and I would like to add a row (called `'Row 5'`) to it. But the row's name has more than one word. So how would I do this?

This is `df`

[image: my dataframe]

This is the code that I tried, but, as you will read, it ends up in an error.

```
sum_part = 37 + 55 + 11 + 21
product_part = 37 * 55 * 11 * 21

pd.Series(
    np.array([37, 55, 11, 21, sum_part, product_part]),
    index=['Column 1', 'Column 2', 'Column 3', 'Column 4', 'Sum', 'Product'],
    name='Row 5')

df = df.append('Row 5')
```

The specific error that this code causes is: `TypeError: cannot concatenate object of type '<class 'str'>'; only Series and DataFrame objs are valid`.

Any help on this would be greatly appreciated! Thank you!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use variable `s` for append `Series`, here `np.array` is not necessary in `Series` constructor:

```
s = pd.Series([37, 55, 11, 21, sum_part, product_part],
              index=['Column 1', 'Column 2', 'Column 3', 'Column 4', 'Sum', 'Product'],
              name='Row 5')
```

Or is possible pass columns names to `index` parameter:

```
s = pd.Series([37, 55, 11, 21, sum_part, product_part],
              index=df.columns,
              name='Row 5')
```

---

```
df = df.append(s)
```

Comment: Even though it isn't necessary, I like to use numpy arrays, just because of all their benefits. Also, thanks for the helpful tip on `df.columns`.